# Getting only DC from TC442A after inputing a sinewave

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet-driver, piezo

[image]
I am trying to increase the current to be able to drive a [piezoelement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FJXY4W8) that has an input current of 273.78 mA. Because the output sinewave is 20mA i connected the output of the [LM358P](https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productfile/41015/lm358p.pdf) to a [TC4427A](https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productfile/41014/TC4427AEPA.pdf) to increase the current and therefore be able to drive the piezoelement. I was expecting a sinewave of the same frequency at Out B terminal of the TC4427A with an increased enough output current to be able to drive the piezoelement, but all am getting is DC of around 12V. I have verified that the at IN B of the TC4427A is a sinewave indeed of 6.3 KHz.

I tried connecting a function generator directly to the TC4427A IN A or B, but still its only DC.

Comment: You seem to have a misconception about what exactly the job of a gate driver is.

Comment: _"...has an input current of 273.78 mA"_ - how did you figure that?

Comment: From the datasheet of the device

Comment: @HakimMarley What datasheet?

Comment: Here is the datasheet that specifies the piezoelements that am trying to drive. https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/p37e.pdf

Comment: But i think the important thing here is not the piezoelement. I would like to increase the current from the LM358P. I linked its datasheet in the post. It only outputs 20mA and i would like to increase that in someway. Maybe am not trying to do it in the right way but any leads and suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend the output current capability of an OpAmp you have many options. A very simple way is to add two BJT transistors. When the load current increases, the voltage across R1 will be high enough to enable base current flow and this adds current via the transistors. However the voltage range of the output is reduced because the BE junctions need around 0.6 V minimum to enable transistor currents.
If the circuit needs a feedback resistor from the output, this must be taken from the emitters now.
There is no current limit included, so the transistors can be destroyed without cooling on high load currents.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR3l3O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another option is to add the transistors in a more dangerous way. In this circuit the current consumed by the OpAmp is measured across R1 and R2 and again the transistors will add current to the output when the amplifier current consumption increases. The circuit however has some drawbacks: There may be a critical high shoot through current when the supply turns on and proper supply decoupling of the OpAmp is not so easy to implement. Such a circuit may be instable and die from high frequency oscillations, I do not recommend it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Pj2D.png)</sup>

To drive a piezo disc, you may abuse a strong gate driver chip, but they are not analog amplifiers and will not process a sine wave analog signal like audio amplifiers do. In my example you feed such a driver with a digital signal of 3.3 V or 5 V amplitude, the needed current is in the µA range. If you use the TC4428A, you have one inverted channel and one not inverted channel. This produces a bipolar voltage difference of +/- 12 V between the two outputs, useful to drive a piezo. I added R1 to limit the peak current. If you hit the self resonance frequency of the disc, the voltage at the disc may be close to a sine wave.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOLS88.png)</sup>

Comment: This os exactly what i was looking for. Thanks mate